# making span and ul on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RJLD/), I wanted to make the span and the ul text to be vertically aligned. Right now the ul text seems to be a bit shifted up a bit, can't figure out why this is. Here's the respective html:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="row sort-container">
            <span class="sort-by brandon-grotesque-regular">
                Lihat berdasarkan:
            </span>
            <ul class="arvo-regular clearfix">
                <li><a class="" href="?sort=popular">Barang Terpopuler</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="?sort=terbaru">Barang Terbaru</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<nobr>` works...but DO NOT use it

Comment: Vertically or Horizontally? your current fiddle shows that it is horizontally and you want to make it the normal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `vertical-align` to middle on the *ul* element.

However, why do you need a layout so complex? It would be better if every element was inline, with no floated  or inline-block box.

Comment: when I do verticle-align middle now the ul is a bit shifted down

Comment: It looks fine to me, could you make a screenshot? However, do you really need the floated and inline-block boxes?

Comment: I basically wanted the ul to be next to the span in one line that's all, hence the inline-block

Comment: You could set `display` to `inline` for the ul and li elements, is there any difference? Or you need the whole ul on the same line (no line breaks in it)?

Comment: I need it to be on the same line

Comment: To prevent line breaks in a element, use `white-space: nowrap`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6RJLD/2/

Comment: it doesn't work with a long text, the <ul> element is being moved above it even with this solution

Answer (score 0):

This is due to browser defaults, just like body element also has a padding...so we often use something like [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to reset all of those in all browsers to 0.

```
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

And remove margin-left from #main .sort-container li {...

Thats it

Comment: Did we understand well about what is the problem? You need vertical alignment by the left side?

Comment: Agree with Carlo Cannas, it doesn't work with a long text, the <ul> element is being moved above it. That said, how should we fix it? ideas?